# Permanent deployment of contracts in Geth

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-deployment, abi

My current method of deploying smart contracts in geth is by generating the `bin` and `abi` files of the corresponding `sol` and then loading the `bin` and `abi` files of the contract into geth using the commands:

`loadScript('contract.bin)`

`loadScript('contract.abi)`

But the issue I am facing with this is that every time I close geth and open it again, the contracts have to be re-deployed again as the existing contracts seem to be missing.

Is there anyway to ensure a permanent deployment of contracts? Or am I missing any critical step?

Answer (score 1):

To deploy a contract, you have to send the contract deployment transaction. 
Using the javascript consol or any javascript script, check this: 
[deploy contract with web3js](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html?highlight=deploy#deploy)